# smooth scrolldown link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been struggling in making a smooth scroll trough divs in my website... What i am trying to do, is to create a link that is linking me to another part of the website. It works but it just sends me there, i want to make it smoother..

Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>I Am Martin</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="ask_box">
        <div class="question">I Am</div>

        <div class="box">
            <a href="#"><span class="answer1">Martin</span></a>
        </div>

        <div class="scroll_down">
            <a href="#try"><button class="btn_down"> &darr; </button></a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="try">

    </div>

</body>
```

**CSS**

```
    *{ 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.ask_box{
    height: 100vh;
    background: #cd3f43;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.question {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

.boxes{
    display: flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
}

.answer1 {
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0.3 0.8;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #cd3f43;
}

.scroll_down{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 50%; 
    right: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.btn_down{
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #cd3f43;
    border: 0;
}

#try{
    height: 95vh;
    background: #292929;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Sorry if my english isn't perfect... I hope you can understand!

**Thank You**

Answer (score 1):

I have used the snippet from [**CSS-Tricks**](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/). Change value `1000` milliseconds to your scroll timing requirement.

```js
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```css
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .ask_box {
    height: 100vh;
    background: #cd3f43;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    font-size: 30px;
  }
  .question {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  }
  .boxes {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .answer1 {
    border: 5px solid white;
    border-radius: 5px;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 800;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 5px;
    padding: 0.3 0.8;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #cd3f43;
  }
  .scroll_down {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    right: 0;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .btn_down {
    height: 30px;
    font-size: 0.6em;
    font-weight: 800;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.85);
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #cd3f43;
    border: 0;
  }
  #try {
    height: 95vh;
    background: #292929;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>I Am Martin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="ask_box">
    <div class="question">I Am</div>

    <div class="box">
      <a href="#"><span class="answer1">Martin</span></a>
    </div>

    <div class="scroll_down">
      <a href="#try">
        <button class="btn_down">&darr;</button>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="try">

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: And just to ask, can you give an opinion of the colors? Im for sure going to keep the red kinda on the first div, but do you like the second's div color?

Comment: It looks good. But better ask here: http://ux.stackexchange.com/ I am not a UX expert :)